# jquery toggleclass to multiple elements usign array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I would like to simply input array inside jquery. Result I want to achieve is this:

```
$(".game-board, .building-tokens").click( function() {
    $( ".mission-cards, .game-board, .building-costs, .mission-cards, .resources-cards, .resources-tokens, .road-card, .game-modal, .dice" ).toggleClass( "game-opacity" );
});
```

But this code is a way too long. And there must be more reasonable solution. So I try to put all the css classes inside an array like this:

```
var classes = [".game-board", ".building-tokens", ".mission-cards", ".building-tokens", ".building-costs", ".mission-cards", ".resources-cards", ".resources-tokens", ".road-card", ".game-modal", ".dice"];

$(".game-board, .building-tokens").click( function() {
    $('"' + classes.toString() + '"').toggleClass( "game-opacity" );
});
```

Why this code doesn't work?

Comment: Don't need extra quotes, use `$(classes.join('')).toggleClass("game-opacity");`

Comment: You can iterate through each element of array using .each() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join() method of array to join all elements and then

```
$(classes.join()).toggleClass("game-opacity")
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm :) Tushar was also correct, execept there should be ".join()", instead of ".join('')"